# Rendering a grails template outside of the application

Tags: grails

I would like to have the flexibility to render templates for emails and files that are not actually present underneath the views/ directory or anywhere actually in the application.

The reason for it is that I can then package and deploy versions of the templates independently of the main application.

So I have the template '_Backup_Email.gsp' defined under 'views/emails/'.

If I do the following:

```
render groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "/emails/Backup_Email", model: [serverGroup: serverGroup])
```

then it renders fine.

If I copy the template to say 'c:/templates/emails/_Backup_Email.gsp' then execute the following:

```
render groovyPageRenderer.render(template: "C:/templates/emails/Backup_Email", model: [serverGroup: serverGroup])
```

I just get a blank screen.

I am obviously missing something here.

Comment: From the manual ... _Note that if the value of the template attribute starts with a '/' it will be resolved relative to the views directory. This is useful for sharing templates between views. Without the leading '/' it will be first be resolved relative to the current controller's view directory then, failing that, the top level views directory. In either case the template file must be named with a leading underscore ('_') but referenced in the template attribute without that underscore or the '.gsp' suffix._ So it looks like you can only use templates within the application...

Answer (score 0):

How about using a property instead of hard coded paths to the templates?

You can start your application with -DtemplateFolder=/home/user/grails/templates.

I would keep the templates as plain text files with the content of the mails etc. You can include the rendered/merged templates in the GSPs which reside 
in the usual grails folders.

Since you are using grails, you must have access to the string template engine of groovy which you can use to merge your templates with the data.

String template engine is documented here

http://www.groovy-lang.org/templating.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have already use application properties for the base directory path to avoid hard coding with the same outcome. The reason I did not include in the example above was to keep the code simpler.